# ¿Como comparar un input con un dato de una tabla php mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, mvc

Buenas noches/dias/tarde

Este es mi primera pregunta y quisiera saber como podria comparar un input con un dato de una tabla, por ejemplo tengo un formulario que se ingresa nick,nombre,contraseña y email ,pero quiero validar que el nick y email que se ingresa en el formulario no se encuentren en la tabla para realizar el registro, pero si se encuentran mandar un error y no se pueda registrar.

pages.php

Lo que hago aqui es recibir los datos del formulario por post siempre y cuando no esten vacio, luego esos datos lo guardo en un arreglo y cada dato lo guardo en una variable para porteriormente pasarlo a la funcion validateDates que esta en la clase user.php.

```
public function register(){


    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && !empty($_POST['nick']) && !empty($_POST['nombre']) && !empty($_POST['contrasena']) && !empty($_POST['email'])) {

        $dates = ['nick' => trim(filter_var($_POST['nick']),FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING),
                  'nombre' => trim(filter_var($_POST['nombre']),FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING),
                  'contrasena' => trim(filter_var($_POST['contrasena']),FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING),
                  'email' => trim(filter_var($_POST['email']),FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)
                ];

                    if($this->userModel->validateDates($dates) == true){
                        echo "Datos Ya ocupados";
                    }else{
                        echo "Bienvenido";
                    }

}

                $this->viewLoad('pages/register');   }
```

user.php

Lo que hago aqui es recibir ese arreglo y realizar una vinculacion con los datos de la tabla usuarios.

```
public function validateDates($dates){
    $this->db->query('SELECT nick, email FROM usuarios WHERE nick=:nick AND email=:email');
    $this->db->bind(':nick',$dates['nick']);
    $this->db->bind('email',$dates['email']);
    $this->db->execute();
    if ($this->db->rowCount() == 1) {
        return $result = $this->db->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }else{
        return false;
    }

}
```

database.php

```
public function getRegisterBd(){
     $this->execute();
     return $this->stmt->fetch(PDO::PARAM_OBJ);
 }

 public function rowCount(){
    return $this->stmt->rowCount();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

puedes cambiar

```html
public function validateDates($dates){
/* en lugar de buscar el nick y el mail  pregunta la cantidad con ese nick o email */
    $this->db->query('SELECT count(*) as cantidad FROM usuarios WHERE nick=:nick AND email=:email');
    $this->db->bind(':nick',$dates['nick']);
    $this->db->bind('email',$dates['email']);
    $this->db->execute();
    /* no se cual es tu funcion para obtener registros de la base de datos pero el resultado del query asignalo a una variable $cantidad
    */

    /* si "cantidad" es mayor que 0  que devuleva verdadero, si no falso  */
    if ($cantidad > 0) {
        return $true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }

}
```

luego en pages.php

```html
if($this->userModel->validateDates($dates) == true){
   echo "Datos Ya ocupados";
}else{
   echo "Bienvenido";
}
```

para los mensajes podrias implementar SweetAlerts  o otra librería que te guste

Comment: si ahi pude corregir mi problema , muchas gracias